# Can I use ng-repeat within one object?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, factory

I'm trying to display pictures saved in my factory.
This is my factory:

```
[
    {
        id: 01,
        title: 'Kabinet in hoger beroep tegen klimaatvonnis',
        text: '...',
        date: '31 oktober, 2015',
        image: 'post1.jpg',
        introtext: '...'
    },
    {
        id: 02,
        title: 'Leraren kritisch over passend onderwijs',
        text: '...',
        date: '05 mei, 2014',
        image: 'post2.jpg',
        image: 'post6.jpg',
        introtext: '...'
    },
    {
        id: 03,
        title: 'Premier Curaçao dient ontslag in',
        text: '...',
        date: '14 april, 2015',
        image: 'post3.jpg',
        image: 'post8.jpg',
        introtext: '...'
    },
    {
        id: 04,
        title: 'Asscher heeft nog geen akkoord met Marokko over uitkeringen',
        text: '...',
        date: '25 januari, 2015',
        image: 'post4.jpg',
        introtext: '...'
    }
```

]

here I want to display it:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1 ng-style="title">{{ currentNieuwsbericht.title }}<br>
        <small>{{ currentNieuwsbericht.date }}</small>
        </h1><br>
        <h2>
            <small style="font-size:24px !important; color: #777;">
                {{ currentNieuwsbericht.introtext }}
            </small>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <p ng-style="text" id="mainText">{{ currentNieuwsbericht.text }}</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
            <a class="thumbnail" ng-repeat="images in currentNieuwsbericht">
                <img src="/src/assets/images/{{currentNieuwsbericht.image}}">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know the ng-repeat that you see now in my code doesn't work but I want something like that, because not every post has more picture.
I hope you understand my problem if you don't just ask what you need to know I'm already struggling with this a whole day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing will just override the attribute `image` value.

Make `image` an array

```
{
    id: 02,
    title: 'Leraren kritisch over passend onderwijs',
    text: '...',
    date: '05 mei, 2014',
    image: ['post2.jpg','post6.jpg'],
    introtext: '...'
}
```

So in your JS you can easily iterate `image`

```
<img ng-repeat='img in images.image' src="/src/assets/images/{{img}}">
```

PS: Please use proper naming convention. `ng-repeat` should be like:

```
ng-repeat="currentImage in images"
```

Comment: The ng-repeat isn't really working, these things are complicated as %$@ :)

Answer (score 0):

You will not receive an error when you have JSON with duplicate key names. However, when you try getting the value, you will get the value of the last property. You should change your data structure to something like `images: ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg']` ant let ngRepeat iterate that.